# Comment disappear after refresh

Tags: support

This happened to me a few times recently where I add a comment under a question or an answer, and after I save the comment, the page reloads (or ajax refreshes, whatever they are doing) and my comment is visible on the page, no errors. I later go back to the question and my comment isn't there any more. But I saw the page after refresh with the comment I made being visible. I sometimes get 503 errors (I'm not sure) when I refresh stackoverflow, but I don't think that's the issue since after saving the comment I can see that it was saved. Any ideas why some of my comments seem to disappear?

Last time I saw this is for `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675363/jquery-reading-log-file-and-printing-output#26675363`. I made a comment under the question, it was there after save, but now it's missing.

**Update**

This just happened today as well, I added a comment under my answer, refreshed the page, it was there, went back to the question after 15 minutes, it was still there, went back to the question an hour later and my comment was missing. Can't find them in timeline either.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26984210/timeline shows only one comment added under my answer but there should be an earlier one.

Comment: You're probably going back to some cached data in your browser from before your comment was added. Next time you go back and your comment disappears, just press refresh and see if it appears. (You should probs change your title to "Comment disappear after going back" or similar, because your description and subject contradict one-another).

Comment: @James Refresh doesn't seem to make it appear. I go back to the question, refresh, then think "What? Where's my comment?", refresh again and the comment is still not there.

Comment: Does it *ever* come back or remain gone? I can see the comment you linked to, can you? When this happens, try clearing all browser cache/history/everything etc, then refresh the page and see if the comment comes. Then test if when you login is it still gone (or) still there? Still sounds like a cache issue.

Comment: This is the direct link to your comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675363/jquery-reading-log-file-and-printing-output#comment41951058_26675363

Comment: @James I updated the question with what happened today, the comment vanished after a while, not even the timeline shows it.

Comment: I'd still guess it's something local to you (or other users would be reporting the same issue). Perhaps someone with more access can see if the comment ever existed, and maybe what happened. How often does this happen to you? What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: @James I'm using latest firefox. It doesn't occur that often, once a week maybe. It's not that important but I was curios as to why. I can't find a pattern on when it happens.

Comment: @James It might happening more often though. These are the ones I noticed.